# How to replace undefined value

Tags: javascript

There are some values returned from my AJAX call that are `undefined` by default. So I did this `function` to replace the value with a message:

```
function replaceUndefined(vl){
    if(typeof(vl) === "undefined"){
        return "0";
    }   
};
```

But while using it in a `undefined` value, it returns "undefined", instead of "0" and even if the value isn't `undefined`, it keeps replacing it!

Any help/suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: pass by reference, pass by value...

Comment: So how are you using the method call? returning a value is not going to do anything if you do not use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return a `0` only when the value is undefined. If it's not undefined the function return `undefined`.

```
function replaceUndefined(vl){
    if(typeof(vl) === "undefined"){
        return "0"; // return 0 as replace, and end function execution
    } 
    return v1; // the above state was false, functions continues and return original value
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function will return `0` only when `v1` will be `undefined` otherwise your function returns always `undefined` because function `if` condition never execute and function doesn't know what to return.

```
function replaceUndefined(vl){
   (typeof(vl) === "undefined")? return "0":return "1";
}
```

One of the solution of this question can be this

```
function replaceUndefined(vl){
   return  (typeof(vl) === "undefined")?  "0": "1";
};
```

It **will** return `0` when `v1` will be `undefined` and `1` when it **won't** be `undefined`

Comment: However consider that you will be replacing valid values with "1" and this does not make sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
function replaceUndefined(vl){
    if(!v1) return "0"; 
};
```

Comment: Down voted because "undefined" will be returned when the if clause evaluates to false - see the correct answer.